# How to add a date to database date field, but only to the fields I extracted earlier

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a sql statement that selects some of my tables with certain criteria from database and puts them in a temp file.

In the same database is a field called CreationDate and it is empty

```
    protected int doWork() throws Exception {
    String data = "";

    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("Test",".txt");

    Connection db_cn = currentDataSource.getDbConnection();
    Statement select_stmt =    db_cn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

   ResultSet r_set;

   String str_sql = "select sap, og_id, kz, sap_order from database where status='A' and ver_status is null order by og_id, kz, sap, sap_order";

   r_set = select_stmt.executeQuery(str_sql);

        FileWriter fileWriter = new      FileWriter(tempFile.getCanonicalPath(), true);

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

   while (r_set.next()) {
       String sap = r_set.getString("SAP");
       String id = r_set.getString("OG_ID");
       String kz = r_set.getString("KZ");
       String order = r_set.getString("SAP_ORDER");

       data = sap + "\t" + id "\t" + kz "\t" + order + "\n";
  bw.write(data);

}

    bw.close();
    fileWriter.close();

    r_set.close();
    select_stmt.close();

   return 0;
    }
```

After the code runs it creates the temp file in which is data that I selected out of the database.

Now my question is, how could I after that my temp file is created, add a date of the creation(the date is enough, it doesnt have to contain hours and minutes of the day) to the same database to my CreationDate field

Problem is I dont know how to get started on this; My idea is to use the calendar from java.util.Calendar to determine the date

```
        Calendar curr_day = new GregorianCalendar();
       int curr_day_format = curr_day.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 10000 +       (curr_day.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) * 100 + curr_day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) ;
```

After that I dont know how I could insert that date back into the database for only the files that have been extracted to the temp txt file

Comment: I am assuming that the records you are retrieving all have keys? if this is the case just update the files where the key values are in the values that you selected

Comment: A `PreparedStatement` which updates all entries of which you select the PK earlier

Answer (score 0):

> String str_sql = "select sap, og_id, kz, sap_order from database where
>   status='A' and ver_status is null order by og_id, kz, sap, sap_order";

Replace the above string with the following:

```
String str_sql = "select sap, og_id, kz, sap_order, cast(sysdatetime() as date) CreateDate from database where status='A' and ver_status is null order by og_id, kz, sap, sap_order";
```

This would not be after the file is created but that seems arbitrary. This is a tsql solution, while the syntax is off the approach is the same, edit your query to add a date to the PL SQL call.

Comment: As a first step, you can format code by using four spaces or wrapping the code in ` characters.  Are you suggesting that the user should replace the first String assignment with the second?  If so, it would make it more clear to state that explicitly.  The user also stated they wish to modify the file with the dates; this solution assumes that there are no modifications to the file between filling it with the DB entries and when the dates are to be added (maybe this is an okay assertion, but would probe the question asker).